# What are the values of a and b so that f(x) is continuous for all x?

Tags: limits, continuity

So I am trying to find the values of a and b such that f(x) is continuous. I know the definition of continuity but I'm having a few problems.

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{lll}
            \frac{ \sqrt{1-x}-1 }{ x }+a \cos (e^\frac{ 1 }{ x }), & \quad x<0\\
            1 & \quad x= 0 \\
            \frac{ \sin (bx^2) }{ 2x^2+3x^4 } + (1+2x)^{1/x}, & \quad x>0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

For $\frac{ \sqrt{1-x}-1 }{ x }+a \cos (e^\frac{ 1 }{ x })$ I can evaluate the first limit but I'm not sure if you can evaluate the cosine limit in any way...

For $\frac{ \sin (bx^2) }{ 2x^2+3x^4 } + (1+2x)^{1/x}$, I am sure I am supposed to use the limit for $\frac {sin(x)}{x}$ for the first part. The second part looks very, very similar to the definition of $e$. In fact, if I use the substitution $u=1/x$ then I get the right form but then the limit become $1/u$ approaching zero instead an I am not sure how to deal with that...

I am not allowed to use L'Hopitals rule or Taylor series for these limits.

Any guidance on this? I feel like I have the gist of it but I am missing something very small and stupid.

Comment: For a start: if $x$ approaches zero from the left hand side, then what does $1/x$ become? And how does that impact the e-power?  Oh yeah, do we still remember what is $cos0$? I think you need that .....

Comment: Well in that case we have a -infinity and then we have $acos(0)$ which is just a. Am I right on that? Then I can easily solve for a from there.

Comment: I just figured out how to do the sin limit too! Now I am just stuck on the supposed e limit on the last part of the piecewise function.

Comment: See John's suggestion

Comment: Yep I got it :) .

Answer (score 1):

Try $x = \frac{1}{2n}$ in that last limit. As $x \to 0$, you have $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Got it! That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might ask yourself "Can I generalize this?" What's $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 +\frac{a}{n} \right)^n$ in general?

Comment: $e^{an}$ I believe.

Comment: Spot on! ...except that the "n" should go away: it's $e^a$.

Comment: Oops! Yes you are right :) .